# How to add 2 yb-master nodes to an existing YugabyteDB cluster

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I’m running YugabyteDB 2.11. I’m trying to add another two master nodes to an existing cluster but no matter what I do it gets stuck on `PRE_VOTER` and never initializes.

Currently, I have 3 masters, 3 tservers, +2 tserver read-replica. Trying to add 2 more masters and tservers. Trying to setup a global YugabyteDB read-only cluster with async-write.

The end goal is to have two masters in NA, two in APAC, two in EU, but it keeps getting stuck in `PRE_VOTER` when we add a new one.

At the moment, all masters are in the same place. I would like to move masters into diverse locations so that they are as reliable as the cluster itself. changing RF size does not seem to change the `PRE_VOTER` stuck issue

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you don't need yb-masters on the read replica side.
Only on the primary cluster: https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/deploy/multi-dc/read-replica-clusters/

You can only have as many masters as the set replication factor on the primary cluster https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/deploy/checklist/#replication

So in your case, you want 1 yb-master in NA, APAC and EU each. Because you’re using 3 replication factor.

The masters should be booted into shell mode (no `--master_address`) before they can be added to the cluster. And then it should work.